# How to set language dynamically in _host.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

In _host.cshtml page I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
}
<html>
@if (cultureInfo.Name == "ar")
{
    <dir ="rtl"></dir>
    <lang ="ar"></lang>
}
else
{
    <dir ="ltr"></dir>
    <lang ="en"></lang>
}
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

but I get this warning

> Warning (active)  HTML0003    Missing attribute name.

On ("rtl","ar","rtl","en")
How can I make it work

Comment: What do you expect to be filling? You are adding a tag like `<dir ="ltr">`, which is a tag with name `dir` having an attribute with no name which is equal to `ltr`. Html gets written like `<tag-name attribute-name="value">` and you are missing the attribute name there (which is exactly the warning you are getting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed missing the attribute name.... I *suspect* what you want to do is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    string dir, lang;
    if (cultureInfo.Name == "ar")
    {
       dir = "rtl";
       lang = "ar";
    }
    else
    {
       dir = "ltr";
       lang = "en";
    }
}
<html lang="@lang" dir="@dir">
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes indeed it is,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Easier to maintain this way.

Why? Let's say one day you want your application to support a new culture, for example spanish written *es*. In the previous answer you would have to modify your conditional statement and handle if the culture name is *es*. With this implementation, you have nothing to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    string lang = cultureInfo.Name;
    string dir = cultureInfo.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft ? "rtl" : "ltr";
}
<html lang="@lang" dir="@dir" data-theme="light">
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maintainability is important, so I’m sure future readers will appreciate this. But can you [edit] your answer to explain _why_ this is easier to maintain?